# JaasSecurityDomain in JBoss AS 7?

Tags: jboss, jaas

Is there a replacement for `JaasSecurityDomain` class used in pre-JBoss AS 7? I'm migrating my application to JBoss AS 7. I've looked through the documentation for JBoss AS 7, and find no mention of org.jboss.security.plugins.JaasSecurityDomain, or possible replacement.